# How to make a count on specific category without using querystring value

Tags: c#, master-pages

I have a leftsidemenu on my masterpage where I'm listing my categories. I would like to make a count of how many products there are in each category.

EXAMPLE:

- Bananas(20)
- Apples(8)
- Strawberries(5)
- Mangoes(9)

My problem is, that I dont have a querystring value since it is at the masterpage, and no values is running.
So far, I have this:

```
var listSubMenu = __account.GetAllProductCategories();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < listSubMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var r = listSubMenu.Rows[i];

    var catid = Request.QueryString["thespecific_category_id_but_how_do_i_get_the_value?"];
    var count = __account.GetSpecificCategory(id);

    sb.AppendFormat(String.Format(@"<li><a href='/account/products.aspx?categoryid={0}'>{1} ({2})</a></li>", r["cat_id"], r["cat_name"], count.Rows.Count));

}
active_sub_products.Text = sb.ToString();

My DataTable:
public DataTable GetSpecificCategory(int categoryid)
    {
        const string request =
            @"
                SELECT * FROM products_category
                WHERE
                cat_id=?categoryid
                AND
                cat_active = 1
                LIMIT 1
            ";
        using (var query = new MySqlCommand(request))
        {
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("?categoryid", categoryid);
            return __dbConnect.GetData(query);
        }
    }
```

Obiously i need the specific categoryid to make a count, but how to I get the id without having querystrings running since it is on the masterpage. Am I missing something obious?

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify directly your SQL query and by using the count function, you'll get what you need. Check here http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php